# Accessibility and required form fields

Tags: forms, accessibility, input-fields, required-fields, optional-fields

As the years have gone by, I've noticed that the usage of the "*" for required on form fields has steadily vanished.

**Are there rules in accessibility that require "require fields" to have an indication?**

I've always thought that the way form fields are presented is that all fields are required, and that if any form field is optional, it will be indicated (usually very obviously saying "optional").

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mark or don't mark required fields if all are required?](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/50584/mark-or-dont-mark-required-fields-if-all-are-required)

Comment: This is a mix of two question that already have complex complete answers: http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/50584/mark-or-dont-mark-required-fields-if-all-are-required, http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/102930/asterisk-is-used-for-required-is-there-any-symbol-used-for-optional

Comment: I don't think this is quite a duplicate question. Those linked ones are about *how* you need to mark optional / required fields, whereas this question is about whether you even need to mark these fields at all.

Comment: ***https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/104172/accessibility-and-required-form-fields***

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This falls under [WCAG 3.3.2 Labels or Instructions](https://www.w3.org/TR/UNDERSTANDING-WCAG20/minimize-error-cues.html).

Required fields must be clearly identified in their label. Asterisks and other images are fine, as long as there is a statement such as "Required fields are marked with an asterisk" in the form.

There are some different ways of achieving this outlined here: https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H90.html

Comment: The question becomes if all of the fields are required, do you have to indicate they are required then?

Comment: Yes, because you may be dealing with those with cognitive impairments that struggle to make assumptions. Also screen reader users just tab between fields and have the label read to them, so it wouldn't be easy for them to scan the form and note that all are required

Comment: @Majo0od, if all your fields are required, visually you might not want an asterisk next to every field because it could make things look too busy, which could also hamper someone with cognitive impairments.  One could easily be distracted by looking at all the asterisks, especially if they're not aligned.  You start seeing patterns and shapes made out of the asterisks.  For visually impaired users, *every* field either needs the 'required' property on the <input> tag or aria-required=true.  There is no visual clutter caused by these properties.

Comment: See that's what I thought too, thanks for clarifying